# Can I change my post type to anything and my site still work?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, pages, post-type

I'm working on an application using WP as my CMS. I was successfully creating new posts and working with them in my app.

But I noticed when visitors went to the website they were being listed in the blog (in the loop). I don't want them to show up there so after doing some research I decided to change my post type from "post" to "page". Now the posts no longer show up on the blog page!

But now, I noticed, my "pages" are showing up as menu items across the top of the page. This is not what I want.

Is it OK to change the type to something else that WP isn't using? For example, can I change the type to "document" and everything be OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### EDIT

I missed the actual question here, it is perfectly save to change `post` to a custom post type. Just make sure to assign the build in taxonomies to the custom post type if you need them and if you already have some kind of hierarchy build through them.

Also make sure that you properly register your post type to suite your exact needs

### ORIGINAL ANSWER

I'm not sure how you would want to have your setup to look like, but from what I read, you can actually do the following

- Create a non-hierarchical post type and simply change your posts to this new post type. Custom post types are excluded from the main query (*except on taxonomy and custom post type archive pages (which you can "switch off")*) and menus. You can use `pre_get_posts` if you need to add custom post type posts to some archive.

  You can also assign custom taxonomies to them (*or even the build in taxonomies `category`, `post_tag` and `post_format`*) and have them work exactly like normal posts. Changing `post` to `page` have other issues that you don't need, as pages have its own methods how it works and how it is dished up in front end. Also, as I previously described in another answer to one of your questions, `page` does not have taxonomie and are not meant to have taxonomies.
- Set a static front page.
- Set a custom tag or category to the posts and use `pre_get_posts` to exclude them from the loop.
- Simply remove the loop from the homepage if you do ot need it. This will however have the drawback that pagination will still work, so you would need to remove this as well

Comment: Thank you once again. So I would call https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type after I create the page each time or just once for the current blog?

Comment: You need to register a post type on every page load on the init hook. Taxonomies work the same

Answer (score 1):

Go-to your dashboard and followed by `Appearance -> menus`.

Here your pages are automatically added as menus.  Just uncheck the checkbox.  The menus won't be there with your page titles.

Comment: Great! Thank you. It looks like I can continue to use pages as long as I turn this option off.